# Check version of Python from Chef CookBook and install package according to the outcome

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I need to write a Chef CookBook that will install some packages according to the version of Python installed in the system.

Is it possible to have following logic in Chef recipe:

```
python_version = `python -V`    # check python version
if python_version == '2.6.6'
  package 'package_a'           # install package_a using Chef package resource
elsif python_version == '3.3.5'
  package 'package_b'           # install package_b using Chef package resource
else
  break                         # stop execution of cookbook
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes.

You should use `shell_out!('python -V').stdout().chomp()` instead of the backticks.

BUT the information already exist in node automatic attributes so you don't have to call `python -V`:

`ohai languages` return:

```
{
  "python": {
    "version": "2.7.3",
    "builddate": "Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41"
  },
  "perl": {
    "version": "5.14.2",
    "archname": "x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi"
  },
  "c": {
    "gcc": {
      "version": "4.6.3",
      "description": "gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) "
    }
  }
}
```

So you should be able to write in your recipe:

```
python_version = node['languages']['python']['version']
if python_version == '2.6.6'
  package 'package_a'           # install package_a using Chef package resource
elsif python_version == '3.3.5'
  package 'package_b'           # install package_b using Chef package resource
else
  raise                         # stop execution of cookbook
end
```

To stop a chef run, you need to use `raise` by [the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#end-chef-client-title-run)

Comment: Can I check the version of Python3? I have installed on my system Python2 and Python3 but `node['languages']` shows only Python2.

Comment: @lmtx Well, chef is not magic. As your initial idea, it will run something like `python -V`under the hood. If your path target python2, you'll get python2 version. You can probably extend the ohai plugin to a custom one to add a python3 entry. But having both version without pyenv to choose them sounds likely to shoot yourself in the foot. All in all this sounds like an XY problem, trying to find something hard where the correct path would be ensuring the target app has the needed packages.

Answer (score 1):

[Ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html) already provides you an automatic attribute for the python version. You can access it as follows:

```
node['languages']['python']['version']
```

The corresponding code is [here](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/python.rb).

The resulting code could look as follows:

```
if node['languages']['python']['version'].to_f < 3
  package "package_a"
else
  package "package_b"
end
```